# Qt Installer Framework issue compiling binarycreator

Tags: qt, frameworks, installation, qt-installer

I have Qt Creator 5.2.0 (MSVC 2010, 32 bit) with mingw48_32.
I am trying to make an installer for my app and i cant compile binarycreator.
I download source code from [Official Link](https://qt.gitorious.org/installer-framework/installer-framework/source/0b5241a696cf05612dae2c8810022f5e205d42df%3a)
When i run project, there show only files with .o and none .exe files. The following error is showing:

```
c:/qt/qt5.2.0/tools/mingw48_32/bin/../lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/4.8.0/../../../../i686-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -linstaller
```

After that, there are more errors, but i think if i fix this they will be fixed too. Here are what is following:

```
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Makefile.Release:84: recipe for target 'bin\binarycreator.exe' failed
mingw32-make[1]: *** [bin\binarycreator.exe] Error 1
mingw32-make[1]: Leaving directory 'C:/Qt/Installer/installer-framework-installer-framework/tools/build-binarycreator-Desktop_Qt_5_2_0_MinGW_32bit-Release'
makefile:34: recipe for target 'release' failed
mingw32-make: *** [release] Error 2
20:30:45: The process "C:\Qt\Qt5.2.0\Tools\mingw48_32\bin\mingw32-make.exe" exited with code 2.
Error while building/deploying project binarycreator (kit: Desktop Qt 5.2.0 MinGW 32bit)
When executing step 'Make'
```

If any1 can help me, please.

Comment: Looks like you're mixing compilers. MSVC is not compatible with MinGW

Comment: I have only one compiler, MinGW. I dont know why in version of Qt is writing msvc. I dont use it. Other projects working fine.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To build an installer for your Application don't bother compile the installer-framework just use the pre-compiled one.

it contains the following files [ /bin ]:

- archivegen.exe
- binarycreator.exe
- installerbase.exe
- repogen.exe

also some examples, and here is the link to download the version 1.4.0
http://download.qt-project.org/official_releases/qt-installer-framework/1.4.0/